# Angular - Conditional module load on lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I wanna load different module in root route of my application based on the group/role of current user. I have a service class where I can get the group of current user, then I would like to load lazy module based on this group. The question is: How can I do that: How can I define a conditional module lazy loading (*loadChildren property*) ? What is the best way to do that?

I think  these solutions:

1 - Inject the service in app-routing.module and do an if else clause on loadChildren property like this: `loadChildren: this.service.group === 'A' ? #moduleA : #moduleB`. Is this possible? If so, is ok to inject services in routes modules?

2 - I could use specific guard for root route and then do a redirect. In that case, I would use a canLoad as I don't want to module event load if the group not match ( [[Difference between Angular's canLoad and canActivate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026045/difference-between-angulars-canload-and-canactivate][1])). If so, I would need to identify if current route is the root to apply the redirect.

I have the following code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
loadChildren: './moduleOne.module#moduleOne', //the module that will be 
//loaded will depends on the group of current user.
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

Thank you all!