# when I refresh the page I return to the main page

Tags: angular

I have such a problem when I am on the User list page and I refresh it takes me to the main page. The page is written in angular on the frontend and .net on the backend.
my app.routing module looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: './modules/user/user.module#UserModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

auto.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<AuthState>
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(loggedIn),
      map((isLoggedIn) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.store.dispatch(logout());
          this.router.navigate([RouterPath.Login]);
        }

        return !!isLoggedIn;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: post the code for `AuthGuard`

Comment: Take a look at whatever loads your angular application in, perhaps the issue is there. Maybe this in an MVC app? Also debug your code specifically your authorization guard by placing some break points and seeing what actually happens on page reload.

Comment: Given that you use the hash stragtegy, it's definitely the guard.

Comment: Use the "canLoad" instead of "canActivate",

Here is the difference given between both in first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026045/difference-between-angulars-canload-and-canactivate

Comment: It might be also an issue with your server. Have it set to return index.html no matter which route was requested and let Angular handle routing. Happened to us

Comment: When I change CanActivate to CanLoad. Nothing displays